# Prove if $A$ is homeomorphic to $B$ then $A-\{a\}$ is homeomorphic to $B-\{b\}$

Tags: general-topology

When dealing with some problems, I frequently got this statement. For example:

If $D^1\cong D^2$, then $D^1-\{0\}\cong D^2 -\{0\}$, thus $S^1\simeq S^2$...

However, why is this always true? The 1-1 correspondence is easy to construct, but how can this be the homeomorphism?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If $A$ is homeomorphic to $B$, then there exists a homeomorphism $f:A\rightarrow B$.  If $f(a)=b$, then $f$ restricts to a homeomorphism from $A-\{a\}$ to $B-\{b\}$.  The important point is that $f(a)=b$.  If you can't find a homeomorphism that does this, then $A-\{a\}$ is not homeomorphic to $B-\{b\}$, for instance if $b$ is isolated, but $a$ is not.

Comment: Thx a lot! Very clear.

Comment: May I say then If $A\cong B$, then $A\setminus \{a\}\cong B\setminus\{b\}$ iff $f(a)=b$?

Comment: @Tojamaru: Consider the case $A=[u,v],$ $B=[x,y].$ We can readily make an increasing homeomorphism $f:A\to B,$ where $f(u)=x$ and $f(v)=y,$ but even though $f(u)\ne y,$ we can say $A\setminus\{u\}\cong B\setminus\{y\},$

Comment: @Tojamaru: I believe we *can* say (at least under certain conditions) that if $A\cong B$ and $A\setminus\{a\}\cong B\setminus\{b\},$ then there is a homeomorphism $f:A\to B$ such that $f(a)=b.$ I'll have to think on it.

Comment: @CameronBuie No.  Consider $A$ and $B$ two point sets, one with discrete topology, other with indiscrete topology.  Then removing one point from each gives homeomorphic one point spaces, but original spaces are not homeomorphic.  Not sure what "certain conditions" would be.

Comment: @StevenGubkin: True, but as I said, "if $A\cong B$ *and* $A\setminus\{a\}\cong B\setminus\{b\}$..."

Answer (score 2):

It is *not* always true, actually. For example, let $A=[a,c)$ and $B=[x,y)$ for some $a,b,x,y\in\Bbb R$ with $a<c,$ $x<b<y.$ Then $A$ and $B$ are readily homeomorphic, but $A\setminus\{a\}=(a,c)$ and $B\setminus\{b\}=[x,b)\cup(b,y)$ are not, since one is connected and the other isn't.

If we happen to know that we have a homeomorphism $f:A\to B$ such that $f(a)=b,$ on the other hand, we can say that $A\setminus\{a\}$ and $B\setminus\{b\}$ are homeomorphic, with the restriction of $f$ to $A\setminus\{a\}$ giving a ready homeomorphism.

Comment: Thx a lot! Very clear and nice example!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't true in general. For example, let $X := S^1\vee S^1$; then certainly $X\cong X$. But if $a$ is the wedge point while $b$ is any other point, then $X\setminus\{a\} \not\cong X\setminus\{b\}$.

A true general statement would be that if $f:A\to B$ is a homeomorphism, then $A\setminus\{a\} \cong B\setminus\{f(a)\}$. The homeomorphism is just the restriction of $f$; continuity of $f$ and $f^{-1}$ follows immediately from the fact that the restriction of a continuous map to a subspace is continuous.

Comment: Thx a lot! Very clear.